# Google map with transit directions won't load locally

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need a page like this one on the contact page of a site

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/transit/transit.html

I thought I'd just look at the source and copy it in my editor so that I could play with the api and customize it.
I c/p the source code in a new file but the page (map and public transit data) won't load in the browser.

Maybe I'm missing a piece of js? I don't think so cause there's only one and it's hosted on Google. So any ideas why this isn't working locally?

Here's the source code, no edits on my part.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
            <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Transit</title>
            <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
            <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                    height: 100%;
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    color: black;
                    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 13px;
            }
            #map {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    right: 50%;
            }
            #panel-wpr {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                    left: 50%;
                    right: 0;
                    overflow: auto;
            }
            #panel {
                    font-family: arial;
                    padding: 0 5px;
            }
            #info {
                    padding: 5px;
            }
            #from {
                    width: 90%;
                    font-size: 1.2em;
            }
            .adp-directions {
                    width: 100%;
            }
            .input {
                    background-color: white;
                    padding-left: 8px;
                    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
                    border-top: 1px solid silver;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
                    border-radius: 1px;
            }
            .time {
                    margin: 0;
                    height: 17px;
                    border: 1px solid;
                    border-top-color: #CCC;
                    border-right-color: #999;
                    border-left-color: #999;
                    border-bottom-color: #CCC;
                    padding: 2px 15px 1px 1px;
            }
            button {
                    border: 1px solid #3079ED;
                    color: white;
                    background-color: #4D90FE;
                    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4D90FE), to(#4787ED));
                    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
                    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
                    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
                    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
                    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
                    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#4d90fe', EndColorStr='#4787ed');
                    display: inline-block;
                    min-width: 54px;
                    text-align: center;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    padding: 0 8px;
                    line-height: 27px;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
                    border-radius: 2px;
                    -webkit-transition: all 0.218s;
                    -moz-transition: all 0.218s;
                    -o-transition: all 0.218s;
                    transition: all 0.218s;
            }
            #info div {
                    line-height: 22px;
                    font-size: 110%;
            }
            .btn {
            }
            #panel-wpr {
                    border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
            }
            #info {
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;
            }
            h2 {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
            }
            </style>
            <script>
            var directions = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var map, transitLayer;

            function initialize() {
                    var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: 14,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.538551, -0.016633),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('go'), 'click',
                    route);

                    var input = document.getElementById('from');
                    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
                    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

                    transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();

                    var control = document.getElementById('transit-wpr');
                    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(control);

                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(control, 'click', function () {
                            transitLayer.setMap(transitLayer.getMap() ? null : map);
                    });

                    addDepart();
                    route();
            }

            function addDepart() {
                    var depart = document.getElementById('depart');
                    for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < 60; j += 15) {
                                    var x = i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
                                    var y = j < 10 ? '0' + j : j;
                                    depart.innerHTML += '<option>' + x + ':' + y + '</option>';
                            }
                    }
            }

            function route() {
                    var departure = document.getElementById('depart').value;
                    var bits = departure.split(':');
                    var now = new Date();
                    var tzOffset = (now.getTimezoneOffset() + 60) * 60 * 1000;

                    var time = new Date();
                    time.setHours(bits[0]);
                    time.setMinutes(bits[1]);

                    var ms = time.getTime() - tzOffset;
                    if (ms < now.getTime()) {
                            ms += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                    }

                    var departureTime = new Date(ms);

                    var request = {
                            origin: document.getElementById('from').value,
                            destination: 'Olympic Park London, United Kingdom',
                            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT,
                            provideRouteAlternatives: true,
                            transitOptions: {
                                    departureTime: departureTime
                            }
                    };

                    var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
                    panel.innerHTML = '';
                    directions.route(request, function (response, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                                    renderer.setDirections(response);
                                    renderer.setMap(map);
                                    renderer.setPanel(panel);
                            } else {
                                    renderer.setMap(null);
                                    renderer.setPanel(null);
                            }
                    });

            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            </script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <div id="transit-wpr">
                    <button id="transit">Toggle transit layer</button>
            </div>
            <div id="map"></div>
            <div id="panel-wpr">
                    <div id="info">
                            <div>
                                     <h2>Transit directions</h2>

                            </div>
                            <div>
                                    <label>from:</label>
                                    <input class="input" id="from" value="Belgrave House 76 Buckingham Palace Road, London, Greater London">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                    <label>to:</label> <strong>Olympic Park London, United Kingdom</strong>

                            </div>
                            <div>Depart at
                                    <select id="depart"></select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn">
                                    <button id="go">Get Directions</button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="panel"></div>
            </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved. I needed to change the url of the js, don't know why it works on Google and not on my pc, anyway

```
//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places
```

becomes

```
//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&amp;libraries=places
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)

The script tag requires the protocol, "http:" on your site or from a local page, but not on the google examples (as they are on the same server).